# Problem encountered while updating a particular cell of a pandas data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in an excel file into a pandas data frame using `pandas.read_excel()` function. The first column is `'Date'`. The first entry into that column has asterisk mark which I want to remove. Here are the first 2 rows of the data frame `DF`.

```
0   1/4/1996*   11540   10841   3592    1827    26476   14510   6900    0   0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 
1   1996-01-11 00:00:00 13881   11735   2532    4188    32064   21989   3819    2586    0   NaN NaN`
```

In order to remove that `*`, I am doing this:`DF['Date'][0] = '1/4/1996'`. However, once I do that, I am getting a warning message

```
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  app.launch_new_instance()
```

and it changes the cell value, but, it also attaches another `'Date'` column at the end of the `df` like this:

```
0   1/4/1996   11540   10841   3592    1827    26476   14510   6900    0   0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1/4/1996
```

I don't understand why this is happening.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone can explain this or point out the correct way of changing the cell value.

Answer (score 4):

Use a combination of string processing and type casting to process the whole column in one swoop:

> excelDF[datecol] = pandas.to_datetime(excelDF[datecol].str.replace('*',''))

I tried using `str.rstrip('*')` but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in how Pandas indices / selectors work. When you only do `Dataframe['Column']`, you are selecting a copy/view of the dataframe. If you do `Dataframe['NewColumn']`, so the `'NewColumn'` column doesn't exist yet, it creates this new column. But if it does exist, it will raise this warning.

What you should do is use `.iloc`, `.ix` or something similar to select data from the frame and be able to alter it.

Or follow @Emre advice.

Comment: yeah specifically, `df.ix[0, 'Date'] = '1/4/1996'`